# Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:thread in Socket Programming Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I recently created a multi-thread server that authenticate the username and password of many clients on the same time from a database with a GUI(between i already created my interface).However,i have encountered this error message when i try to run the code:Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused:connect. between this is my first time asking a question here.

This is my server code:

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try{
        ServerSocket server_socket=new ServerSocket(6969);
        while(true){
        Socket client=server_socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Un nouveau client est connecté");
        Client_Thread clientSock= new Client_Thread(client);
        new Thread(clientSock).start();
        }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
        }
class Client_Thread implements Runnable {
private final Socket clientSocket;


public Client_Thread(Socket socket) { this.clientSocket = socket; }
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
         String name;
         String password;
            while ((name = in.readLine()) != null &&(password= in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.printf(
                    "nom d'utilisateur recue du client: %s\n",
                    name); 
             out.println(name);
             System.out.printf(
                    "mot de passe recue du client: %s\n",
                    password); 
             out.println(password); 
             Connection sql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/school","root", "Canada20Canada20");
             Statement stm = sql.createStatement();
             ResultSet  rs = stm.executeQuery("Select * from student");
             while(rs.next()) {
          String user= rs.getString("select username from student");
              String motdepasse = rs.getString("select password from student");
              if(name.equals(user)&&password.equals(motdepasse)){
              System.out.println("nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe correcte");
              }else{
              System.out.println("nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe incorrecte");
              }
              in.close();
              out.close();
         }
            }      
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This my client code:

```
public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Client() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        Socket SocketClient = new Socket ("127.0.0.1",6969);
        BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (SocketClient.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream in= new PrintStream(SocketClient.getOutputStream());
        in.println(jTextField1.getText());
        in.println(String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));
        if (out.readLine().equals("true")){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
             "utilisateurs trouvable",
             "WELCOME",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jLabel3.setText("Connexion avec succés");
        }else{
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
             "utilisateurs introuvable",
             "ERREUR",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             jLabel3.setText("Connexion échouer");
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        
    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The full error message is:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at essai.Client.jButton1ActionPerformed(Client.java:116)
at essai.Client.access$100(Client.java:16)
at essai.Client$2.actionPerformed(Client.java:58)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: You are running the server on port `6969` and the client is connecting to port `5201`? How will that work. Connect the client to port 6969, on run the server on port 5201, either of one will do the job

Comment: i connected the server and the client to the same port but the the error is still present

Comment: Update the question with your edit and latest error.

Comment: There should be a "caused by:" in the stack trace …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the listening server was not configured correctly, And when you push the button, The error is thrown. the possible problem is that because the `ServerSocket` IP address was not configured explicitly then it gets your machine IP address something that your router assigned to your machine. I believe to fix this problem, you should set the IP address of the listening server explicitly. see [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

```
ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)
Create a server with the specified port, listen backlog, and local IP address to bind to.
```

Comment: it was indeed the problem,thank you so much ,i appreciate your help.